# How can I add sourcemap in Keystone js

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I'm trying to understand/find how KeystoneJS compiled LESS file to .css to implement sourcemap plugin or something like this. Because it's really hard to debug. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up gulp you can do it. You can choose to include gulp with the yo generator.

In `gulpfile.js` you'll need to set up a:
`gulp.task('less', function(){ ... })`
where you configure less to use a sourcemap.

More info on NPM: [gulp-less-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less-sourcemap)

Comment: Thx, I already did this, and it's work for me. I just want add, if someone will looking for this issue, one more details - don't forget comment line // 'less': 'public', in keyston init function in keystone.js file.